# Rails rescue_from not catching exception in same file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, exception

So in my `application_controller` I have a helper method that raises an exception in a certain case, and a `rescue_from` for that exception in the same file. The structure looks something like the following:

`application_controller.rb:`

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

    helper_method :my_method
    def my_method
        begin
            # some code
        rescue xyz
            # some code
            unless something
                raise MyException.new()
            end
        rescue
            raise MyException.new()
        end

    end

    rescue_from 'MyException' do |e|
        # some code
    end

    class MyException < StandardError; end
end
```

For some reason, when `MyException` is raised in my helper method, it is not caught by the `rescue_from`. I'm honestly not sure how to proceed...I don't think putting the `rescue_from` before the method would affect anything, since I have more than one handler defined like this and they work fine.